# How to access "Romware" files from CD-ROM .iso image?

Tags: windows, iso-image

I have an `.iso` image of a CD-ROM that was released in 1990. There are two `.exe` files on there which I can not open. There is also a `.bat` file on there which gives an error message "not supported 16bit application" when trying to run.

[image: error message image]

It seems that `.bat` tries to run one of the .executables; `RW20.exe`. The name of this`.exe` and the "Romware™" sticker on the front of the CD-ROM make me think this is where I have to start looking but searching on how to open those files lead to nothing for me.

Comment: Old 16-bit software won't run in any modern or even old Windows. That is probably MS-DOS software.

Comment: Oh, and "Romware" is a company that still exists but I doubt they'll answer if you ask them about a 90s CD.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thanks for the info. You think it would be possible to run it under MS-DOS in a VM?

Comment: Possibly. There's also MS-DOS emulators but that's not my thing so can't help you that. But I'm sure Google can.